# SQL QUERY, 2 Summed Values (Columns) with same grouped by except that years are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

SQL Newbie here. I would like to ask for help from anyone regarding getting the sum of 2 values based on multiple groups but the only difference is the years. Please see my sample below:

Database:

```
=============================================
NAME     COUNTRY      CITY     YEAR     VALUE
=============================================
Alpha    Philippines  Manila   2015     5
Beta     Philippines  Cebu     2015     3
Alpha    Philippines  Cebu     2015     4
Alpha    Philippines  Cebu     2015     1
Alpha    Philippines  Manila   2015     3
Alpha    Philippines  Manila   2015     5
Alpha    Philippines  Manila   2014     10
Beta     Philippines  Cebu     2014     1
Alpha    Philippines  Cebu     2014     15
=============================================
```

Result:

```
============================================================
NAME     COUNTRY      CITY     VALUE (2014)     VALUE (2015)
============================================================
Alpha    Philippines  Cebu     15               5
Alpha    Philippines  Manila   10               13
Beta     Philippines  Cebu     1                3
============================================================
```

Not all columns came from same table. Say:
1) Name, Country, and City - `dbo.Product`
2) Year - `dbo.Calendar`
3) Value - `dbo.SellThru`
***Key value is `CompanyKey`

I hope I explained it correctly and thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum the values into different columns using a conditional so that each column only gets the rows for that year.

Something like this (I didn't actually run it so perhaps the syntax has some small error):

```
SELECT name, country, city,
   SUM(CASE year WHEN 2014 THEN value ELSE 0 END) as Value2014,
   SUM(CASE year WHEN 2015 THEN value ELSE 0 END) as Value2015
FROM <table-name-here> 
GROUP by name, country, city
```

Comment: Hi eugenioy. Thank you so much for your quick response. This is what I'm looking for. I've been playing with UNION and JOIN for about a week now. Never thought it's that simple. Thanks man! You saved me from being kicked out of my job. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PIVOT` table operator:

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Country, 
  City, 
  [2015] AS 'Value(2015)', 
  [2014] AS 'Value(2014)'
FROM table1 AS t1
PIVOT
(
   MAX([Value])
  FOR [Year] IN([2015], [2014])
) AS p;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c8a6a/2)

In your case, instead of `FROM table1 AS t1`, use a subquery that selects the five columns `NAME     COUNTRY      CITY     YEAR     VALUE` from the three tables.

---

### Update

```
SELECT
  ..
  ..
  ,[2014] AS 'Value(2014)' 
  ,[2015] AS 'Value(2015)' 
FROM
(
   -- Here you should put the subquery
   SELECT
     dmCal.sFiscalYYYY
     ,ftSel.nNetUnits
     ..
     ..
     -- Select other columns here.
   FROM ftSellthru ftSel (NOLOCK) 
   INNER JOIN dmCalendar dmCal (NOLOCK) 
           on ftSel.iTransactionDateKey = dmCal.iCalendarKey 
) AS t
PIVOT 
(
   MAX(nNetUnits) -- Only nNetUnits without the alias ftSel as it is not recognized here
   FOR sFiscalYYYY IN([2015], [2014]) 
) AS p;
```

Comment: Hi Mahmoud. Thank you for your help man. However, I can't seem to make this work. With the help of a fellow here, I found a simple solution but I am really interested on this one. Maybe because of this?

...
       ,[2014] AS 'Value(2014)'
       ,[2015] AS 'Value(2015)'
FROM ftSellthru ftSel (NOLOCK) 
 INNER JOIN dmCalendar dmCal (NOLOCK) on ftSel.iTransactionDateKey = dmCal.iCalendarKey 

PIVOT
(MAX(ftSel.nNetUnits)
  FOR dmCal.sFiscalYYYY IN([2015], [2014])
) AS p
...

Comment: @DarwinJasonPajares - This is not the correct way, you have to enclose the first query inside a subquery, see my update in my answer.